# How can I post formatted text with local image on Facebook or Twitter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode

I want to share my local saved image and formatted text on Twitter or Facebook using my application.

For example, I want to combine both image and bolded text in a single post.

Are there any APIs available for it?

Comment: Please accept some of your past question's answers if anything in this forum has been helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/) in your iOS application.

It is very easy to integrate a variety of Social Networking sites.

Comment: Definitely have a look at ShareKit. I am using sharing in another app now and this time round I am using ShareKit.

Comment: Does Sharekit allow posting local image and text to twitter/facebook? I couldn't find any solution in sharekit. It just allows either image or text or url to post.

Answer (score 0):

I find ShareKit pretty hard to use for a simple task like sharing to Facebook, Twitter or Email. Therefore I wrote a simple lib called [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare). Maybe you wanny give it a try?

```
BMFacebookPost *post = [[BMFacebookPost alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"Simple sharing via Facebook, Email and Twitter for iOS!" 
                        descriptionText:@"Posting to Facebook, Twitter and Email made dead simple on iOS. Simply include BMSocialShare as a framework and you are ready to go." 
                        andHref:@"https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare"];    

[post setImageUrl:@"http://www.blockhausmedien.at/images/logo-new.gif" 
         withHref:@"http://www.blockhaus-media.com"];

[[BMSocialShare sharedInstance] facebookPublish:post];
```