# Posting message along with an image on Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

How do I post a message on Facebook while uploading an image on Facebook?

In my project I'm using `FBFeedPost` for uploading images on Facebook and is working fine, but I have to post a message along with the image.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437574/) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881676/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391136/) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498398/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637252/) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351830/) [&c.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=message+facebook+%5Bobjc%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/), easily setup and supporting the facebook features you requested.

After installing authorization is done with just:

```
SHKSharer *service = [[[SHKFacebook alloc] init] autorelease];
[service authorize];
```

After that it's

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:myImage title:@"Look at me!"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

for an image and for text:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:text];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Comment: how would you add an image, a url and a title? SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:myImage url:url title:@"Look at me!"]; gives a too many arguments error. thanks

Comment: I would also suggest you give [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare) a try, a lib I wrote. It is way simpler than ShareKit in case you only want to use Facebook, Twitter and Email.