# I need to allow an app user to post something on their Facebook as their status, from with my app... what do I need? Facebook connect?

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, share

I haven't ever done anything with Facebook development before, and it seems like you can do quite a bit of stuff. I'd prefer to not drown in information, so I am coming here to hopefully find out exactly what I need to do to get what I want to get done.

I have an html page in a `UIWebView` that displays the content of a page just great. On the page, there is a quote, and I need to be able to allow users to share that quote on their Facebook page as their status. So I guess have a "like" button that would then allow them to sign in and post (providing the content of the quote for them).

On Twitter, you can do something like this I think:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=The quote you want to post">
```

What do I need to do to get the desired result for Facebook?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902935/) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437574/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881676/) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391136/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498398/) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637252/) [7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351830/) [&c.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+post+%5Biphone%5D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) is all you need

Oh, and btw, now there is a "better" way to post on Twitter, check the [Web Intents](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/intents)