# How to do wall post on facebook with image stored on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application in which i have to post image on Wall of facebook.
Now problem is i used GraphAPI facebook and i have to pass link of photo but i have photo in my iPhone and not on any server.
So how do i post wall with image and other parameters without URL of image?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437574/) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881676/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391136/) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498398/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637252/) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351830/) [&c.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+%5Biphone%5D)

Comment: My Actual question is different then all these...

Comment: i know how to upload photo in photo album and i know how to do wall post..but how to do wall post with local image and not with URL having all parameters like description,link,message,etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use NSURLConnection ASIHttpRequest library for downloading the images from a url.

```
You will have to do the following:
1. Create a NSUrlConnection and implement the delegate methods
2. Pass the url in your request and you will get the data in -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection
3. You can then create a UIImage from this data using UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:activeDownloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FBStreamDialog *dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";

NSDictionary *params = nil;
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:params dataParam:(NSData*)wallImage];
[dialog show];
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

--

**Actually, posting an image to the Facebook wall has to be from the web. So you will have to upload the image first; maybe try a 3rd party service like twitpic or something, return the response url and place it in your params.**

--

You can use the following to post with image to Facebook. You can also replace `UIImage` with a physical URL as well.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               kAppID, @"app_id",
                               @"http://bit.ly/dDZQXt", @"link",
                               @"www.has.to.be.web.based.com", @"picture",
                               EasyStrings(@"Mobile Profiles for ",device), @"name",
                               EasyStrings(@"Current Profile: ",currProfile), @"caption",
                               @"I am using Mobile Profiles for iPhone, iPod touch and iPad.", @"description",
                               message,  @"message",
                               nil];
[_facebook dialog:@"feed"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];
```

### What it will look like:

[image]

The house icon is loaded from `[UIImage imageNamed:@"something.png"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the facebook demo app. It uses the modal view to select a picture from your phone. You can use this code, granted you must add two buttons (i.e., selectPicture button and a uploadPhoto button) -- also be sure to add  to UIViewController in the .h file:

```
/**
 * Upload a photo.
 */
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {

  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 image, @"picture",
                                 nil];

  [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                        andParams:params
                        andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];

}

/**
 * Select a photo.
 */
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction) selectPicture:(UIButton *)sender;
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare) which is a simple lib I wrote. It is exactly doing what you want. Upload some local image (and even open a dialog for the user to add a comment) to the user's wall:

```
BMFacebookPost *post = [[BMFacebookPost alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[[BMSocialShare sharedInstance] facebookPublish:post];
```