# how can i post image source on Group wall of facebook in iphone

Tags: iphone

How can i post local image source(saved into iPhone photo library) on facebook group wall without image url through Graph API?

Comment: Check this.

[How to do wall post on facebook with image stored on iPhone?][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5974356/790794

Comment: i dont want to share image on wall i have done it successfully but problem is with post on group wall.I have get listing of all of my Groups on facebook and i want to post local image on any of those.